# WebsphereND nodeagent windows service is not stopping members

Tags: java, networking, deployment, websphere

I have setup WebsphereND nodeagent as a windows service and able to start the node from service along with its registered members.

The problem is when I'm stopping the nodeagent from the windows service its getting stopped but it's members keep on running ( its not showing on deployment manager console but any application deployed is accessible ).

What could be the cause of this behaviour , in the member there is a setting to start automatically along with nodeagent but I'm not able to find any configuration where members will stop along with nodeagent.

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's expected. Does some doc  imply it?

Comment: As per wasserviceutility members can't be configured as a window service , only node and cell is allowed. If that is the case how would to stop the member only by using windows service ? I believe through node but its not working

Comment: The node agents are there to receive administration commands from the dmgr. The expected way to stop/start servers is via the dmgr (console, wsadmin, etc).  Locally, there's also bin/stopServer.bat

Comment: Ok so shall I assume there is a no way to setup a windows service to stop/start a server in WAS ND setup and for this requirement we can use a normal WAS ( without ND ) where we can configure a server as a windows service?